# Why does calling an empty function in my Livewire component mutate the data, making films_count undefined?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have created a simple example to demonstrate the issue.

##### Database

There are two models with a many-to-many relationship. A film can have many tags, and a tag can belong to many films.

##### Livewire

My livewire component consists of the following two files:

```php
class Test extends Component
{
    /** @var Collection */
    public $allTags;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->allTags = Tag::query()
            ->withCount('films')
            ->orderByDesc('films_count')
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->get()
        ;

        info($this->allTags); // contains the films_count field on each tag
    }

    public function blah()
    {
        info($this->allTags); // films_count is missing
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test');
    }
}
```

and

```html
<div x-data="{ allTags: {{ $allTags }} }">
    <button wire:click="blah()">Click me</button>

    <template x-for="(tag, index) in allTags" :key="tag.slug">
        <div :index="index" x-text="tag.name + ' x ' + tag.films_count"></a>
    </template>
</div>
```

##### The problem

When I first load the page with the component I get the expected result - A list of tags, each including the number of films that have that tag, eg.

```
Action x 8
Sci Fi x 6
Netflix x 5
```

However, as soon as I click the button (which literally does nothing), the data is mutated and the films_count field is no longer present on the objects in the Livewire component or alpinejs x-data. The page display changes without reloading the page (which I would expect), but looks like this:

```
Action x undefined
Sci Fi x undefined
Netflix x undefined
```

By dumping the contents of allTags on the backend, you can see that film_count is present in allTags at the end of the mount method, but missing in the blah method. This makes no sense to me. The blah method is not updating anything that would cause Livewire to change its state and after mounting, is the only function that is called. But the state is being changed.

**Why does calling an empty function in my Livewire component mutate the data, making films_count undefined?**

Comment: mount() will work only one time when the page is loaded. That's why you are getting error when you call allTags in blah(). Solution is to get allTags in render() function.

Comment: I understand that mount only gets called once. But allTags should only need to be set once as it's a public variable on the component?

Comment: Please try the solution as I mentioned. It will work I'm hopeful!